# Как сохранить HTML в текстовый документ?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Имеется большой список с checkbox-ами. Пользователь с помощью checkbox-ов отмечает некоторые элементы этого списка. При нажатии на кнопку сохраняются все значения отмеченных checkbox-ов (Атрибуты name='ind' и value='@term.Id').
С помощью JQuery получаю массив значений:

```
var Marks = $("input[name=ind]:checked").serialize();
```

Данные принимают вид

```
ind=1&ind=2 ...
```

Далее открываю новое окно (передаю данные через адресную строку):

```
window.open(url+Marks, "Выгрузка");
```

Сервер обрабатывает Get запрос следующим образом:

```
        public ActionResult UnloadTerms(int[] ind)
    {
        HttpContext.Response.Clear();
        HttpContext.Response.Charset = "";
        HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/msword";
        string strFileName = "Выгрузка " + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd:MM:yyyy") + ".doc";
        HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=" + strFileName);
        StringBuilder strHTMLContent = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (int id in ind)
        {
            TermCardViewModel model = new TermCardViewModel(Manager.GetTerm(id), Manager.GetDefinitionsList(id, 0), Manager.GetAssociationsList(id));
            if (model.Term != null)
            {
                strHTMLContent.Append(RenderViewToString(this, "Partial/PartialTermCardForWord", model));
                strHTMLContent.Append("<br /><br /><br />");
            }
        }
        HttpContext.Response.Write(strHTMLContent);
        HttpContext.Response.End();
        HttpContext.Response.Flush();
        return View();
    }
```

Грубо говоря, я формирую частичное представление для каждого элемента с *ID* из массива *ind*, а затем склеиваю всё вместе и отдаю пользователю. У него открывается окно сохранения файла, файл сохраняется, всё отлично.

Суть проблемы: если выбрано большое кол-во записей, то Url получается слишком длинный - сервер отказывается его обрабатывать:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Открываю новое окно, чтобы пользователь мог работать в старом, пока выполняется "выгрузка".
Собственно вопрос: можно ли как-то иначе передать большой объем данных в новое окно или осуществлять выгрузку в основном без временной потери работоспособности?

Comment: Есть такая штука в http как атрибуты и параметры.

Comment: Вот пример как добавить произвольный атрибут/хидер в заголовок пакета: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6539342/how-to-add-headers-in-httpcontext-response-in-asp-net-mvc-3

Answer (score 1):

Если никак не получается сократить длинный URL, но работать с ним нужно, то можно воспользоваться директивами настройки веб-сервера для увеличения значений:

для apache [LimitRequestLine](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#large_client_header_buffers)

Пример: `LimitRequestLine 4094`

для nginx [large_client_header_buffers](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#large_client_header_buffers)

Пример: `large_client_header_buffers 4 8k;`